# Что делать, если сниффер отображает только пакеты по UDP протоколу?

Tags: c++, сниффер

Добрый день. Написала свой сниффер, работающий в "неразборчивом" режиме (Promiscuous mode), из которого хотела сделать анализатор протокола НТТР, но проблема в том, что он отображает только пакеты, принятые по протоколу UDP. В своём коде ошибок не могу найти. Попробовала скачать готовый сниффер - проблема та же. В чём может быть причина и как заставить программу вывести информацию о каком-нибудь НТТР запросе?

Comment: А HTTP запрос идет на вашу машину ? Может вы видите не все UDP, а только широковещательные ? В наше время, тупых хабов, через которые проходил весь трафик уже не осталось. Все существующие свитчи достаточно умны, что бы отправлять на конкретный порт только те пакеты, которые ему предназначены и promiscous на вашей сетевухе их конечно совершенно не интересует

Comment: С помощью чего вы сниффер писали? И зачем?

Comment: Я запускала сниффер как на обычной ОС, так и на собственном виртуальном сервере с поднятым НТТР. Более того, пробовала запускать на нём сайты не только через браузер, но и через такие утилиты как putty и netcat. Ничего не меняется, по-прежнему только UDР запросы проходят.

Comment: Сниффер писала на С++ в рамках курсовой работы. Если быть точной, моя цель - как раз разработать анализатор протокола НТТР на основе сниффера, а потом с его помощью программно собирать различную статистику.